# durandal/breeze updated now my knockout if: binding isn't working

Tags: data-binding, breeze, knockout-2.0, durandal

I've just updated my project with newer versions of Breeze (from 1.3.1 to 1.3.6) and Durandal (1.1.? to 1.2.0) Knockout(2.2.1 not changed).

I have a knockout binding that looks like this:

```
<div id="payerListBody" class="span11" data-bind="foreach: payers">
  <div class="row" data-bind="click: $parent.payerClicked">
    <div class="span1" data-bind="text: shortName"></div>
    <div class="span5" data-bind="text: name"></div>
    <div class="span2" data-bind="if: contact">        <---- this binding now produces an error
      <div class="span2" data-bind="foreach: contact().phones()">
        <span class="span2" data-bind="text: fullPhone() + '-' + contactScope().name()"></span>
        <br />
      </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-state-highlight" data-bind="click: $parent.payerClicked"></div>
</div>
```

which worked fine before the update and now gives me an error:

"Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: contact is not defined;
Bindings value: if: contact"

The Contact attribute is a non-required complex type associated with the Payer class:

```
  public class Payer : BaseData
  {
    public Payer()
    {
      Incentives = new List<PayerIncentiveProgram>();
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    public Contact Contact { get; set; }
    public Boolean HasIncentiveProgram { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PayerIncentiveProgram> Incentives { get; set; }
  }
```

Thanks for any insight...

Comment: How do you load the `payers` collection? Can you please post your `EntityQuery`?

Comment: the entity query for payers is:          var query = EntityQuery.from('Payer')
          .expand("contact.emails.addressContactScope, contact.phones.contactScope, incentives");  Please note that the contact is a non-required attribute.  My if: binding is attempting to identify a null in that attribute and skip the markup if null.

Comment: Please try it with: `<div class="span2" data-bind="if: $data.contact">`

Comment: Yes, thank you. That worked. So, now I'm seeing that all my foreach: bindings are having the same issue.  I guess I now have to put a guard "if:" binding above any items that may be null :-(.  Is this a "best practice" that the new versions are pushing me towards?

Comment: No your contact().phones() should be contact().phones, your fullPhone() should be fullPhone, contact().name() should be contact().name.  While nemesv is correct that if $data works, it would make more sense to use either a container less if or a with binding there.